# Exposing simple Java application methods through HTTP calls (Not a web application)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

I have a simple Java application (Not a web application) and using maven I distribute it through a Jar file. I need to expose some of its public methods through HTTP(Similar to rest APIs) so that other applications can reuse it by making rest calls.
Doing some research I see for example, Jersey is an option but that seems to be only available for Java Web applications. I also came across HTTPComponents + HTTPClient but the code is much more complicated than how Jersey is.

My question is whether there is a simple solution for Java applications to expose public methods through HTTP.

Thank you,
Sara

Comment: As soon as you have HTTP endpoints you are firmly within web application territory. I wouldn't get hung up on those semantics. Jersey is a great library for rest stuff in Java.

Comment: Thanks for your response @DejaVuSansMono. What I meant is that I don't have web.xml also I still would like to expose the application strictly as a jar. The way that I need those users access those rest URLs is by adding my jar to their application and then make rest calls to use those APIs I am going to expose. I know this is possible through httpcomponents I find it cumbersome and looking for a better solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "as a jar"? If you're talking about having them include the jar in their own programs, then it's simpler and more efficient to just make direct Java calls. If you're talking about a runnable jar that's its own program, Spring Boot will package up everything you need, including an embedded Web server, into a single jar for you.

Comment: If you want to expose interfaces to be invoked over http by other java running applications you can use Spring HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean...

Comment: @chrylis , it means they don't have access to the code and the only thing I am going to share with them is a built jar file out of my application. It is a runnable jar. Thanks for your suggestion I'll take a look at it. I don't have a Spring project it is a simple Java project but I'll see what I can get. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have any of the Web functionality yet. Spring Boot would allow you to very simply wrap those API calls with a Web interface. That said, if they have your runnable jar, they have exactly as much access to your code as if you distributed it as a library, and you might as well save everyone the trouble.

Comment: Thanks everyone, for sharing your thoughts. The user was asking for rest APIs rather than simple Java APIs. I am not exactly sure why. I am going to follow up and if they still need rest I'll wrap the project in a web format and use the libraries you have suggested here. Otherwise, I'll simply share the jar and the library through Java APIs. Thanks again. Sara

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the comments for the answer. Multiple Web technologies were suggested and seems like I have to convert the project to Web based application if we'd like to distribute as rest APIs and otherwise, if user agrees just use the Jar and Java APIs. Thanks.